# Implementing drag and drop into a image viewer

Tags: java, image, swing, drag-and-drop

Im an intermediate programmer making my own little image viewer. Currently I'm looking into implementing a Drag-and-Drop feature. Ive done some research and have seen that you need to use image icon b/c it is serializable, the code seems pretty complicated. The DnD would be on images dragged to the panel. I have a few questions.

1. what swing component would work best to hold the image?
2. what would be the easiest way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 3):

> what swing component would work best to hold the image?

Why not a [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)?

Comment: since very short answer, but an answer to OP's 1st. question +1

Answer (score 2):

Implementing drag-and-drop functionality is not that hard

- Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html)
- Create your own [`TransferHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html) as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/transferhandler.html)
- [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setTransferHandler%28javax.swing.TransferHandler%29) your `TransferHandler` on your Swing component
- Check out which [`DataFlavor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/DataContentHandlerFactory.html) is used when dragging your image data (see also [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dataflavor.html)) and make sure your handler accepts it
- Test it